# How do I advertise an Area 51 proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51, advertising

I'd like to advertise some of the Area 51 proposals. I've already told some of my friends with similar interests about the site. How should I proceed when 'recruiting' acquaintances? Are there any concise, well-worded examples?

Comment: To suggest advertising copy text, I'd need to know which proposal you have in mind.

Comment: @MatthewMartin: In my case it's about the game of Go

Comment: There already is a board game stack exchange. I would suggest the best way to promote is to be active on the "go" tag http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go and someday there may be enough going on on that tag that a new site will be created, sort of in the way that Computer Science split off Stack Exchange and TeX split off Math Exchange