# Question doesn't load

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

[How do I advertise an Area 51 proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60539/how-do-i-advertise-an-area-51-proposal)

Doesn't load for me in firefox until I change the URL to:

[How do I advertise an Area 51 proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60539)

**Edit**

It's returning a 1px by 1px gif for some reason, no page data!

Comment: Problem is on your side - FF 3.6.6

Comment: Works for me. Firefox 3.6.8.

Comment: Firefox 3.6.8 - still not working, cleared cache etc etc.

Comment: I don't even think that last part is processed at all; you could link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60539/i-have-a-very-real-fear-of-unicorns-attacking-my-village and it will work equally well (although it does change the link title text, which is fun)

Comment: Yup, your unicorn link works fine but the original isn't working which is what the link to on the newest question page links to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if you can go here:

[Question doesn't load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60541/advertise-dentures-for-toothless-crims)

If you can't, and it's the same problem, you may have Adblock on or a really aggressive filter that strips any content path related to advertising to a whitewashed 1 pixel image of nothingness.

Since the URL contains the word "advertise" you're looking at that as a likely suspect for the nail.

Comment: I'm not running any adblock software (unless firefox has some built in) and that link works fine for me.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, you were all right it's Kaspersky anti banner protection.