# Promote Area 51 proposal on other SE sites

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-promotion

How would one go about promoting a Area 51 proposal on another SE site?  Should I form a question out of the promotion and post it?  That seems a bit odd.

Related: [How do I advertise an Area 51 proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60539/159941)

Comment: You don't, Stack Exchange promotes proposals as ads on the site. All you can do is share the proposal with your friends through other channels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can understand wanting to share your enthusiasm for your favorite proposal, but advertising them on a meta site — even if it is veiled as a question — would not be appropriate. That is not the purpose of meta; Off topic.

We have already started grouping proposals into "Categories" so we can advertise them to sites that might share an interest. Beyond that, you should be going out to the wider internet to evangelize your favorite proposal. Cross-promoting proposals *within* the network has to fall to the developers through whatever means *they* can come up with.

Comment: I hadn't planned on posting it on meta.  I just thought that this would be the place to ask the question.  Thanks for your response.  I suspected that was the case.  I did find an alternative though: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/456/community-promotion-ads-2h-2011/501#501  I hope that's acceptable.

Comment: @Ryan: Advertising proposals in community promotion ads is okay. The requirements are still pretty loose until we see how the advertising will be used.