# Is it acceptable to promote an Area 51 site against suitable questions in established SE sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51, etiquette

[This question](http://answers.onstartups.com/q/34228/16748) was criticised as being too localised (to New Zealand) on the Answers On Startups site.

I'm trying to get some momentum going on an [Area 51 proposal relating to New Zealand](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39444/new-zealand?referrer=atzaySlKcVezF3Sf0xl57Q2), and I'm wondering whether it's appropriate to add a comment to that question which suggests that the New Zealand proposal would be a good place to get an answer to such a question (though obviously not immediately).

I see this as an issue that isn't so much specific to Area 51 (which doesn't have a meta site anyway) as it is to general SE etiquette, so I've posted it here.

---

Now that the question is posted, I see there are existing questions covering this:

- [Is it ok to cross-promote, by mentioning area 51 proposals on related SO/SF/SU questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56130/171535)
- [Promote Area 51 proposal on other SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96910/171535)

Comment: The [Area51 discussion zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/) serves as Area51's Meta. But your question is fine here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a general sense… ***NO*, it is *not* appropriate** to advertise or promote an Area 51 proposal by linking to it from a related Stack Exchange question.

There may be *very* limited cases where a question is being closed as obviously off topic — I might look the other way if you were simply offering some alternative advice, as in: *"Your question is off topic, but you may want to support this proposal."* But don't start trolling the Q&A sites to find support for your favorite proposal. This should be somewhat rare.

I would not expect to see comments in the general Q&A soliciting users to come support a proposal… **even if** that question would be on topic on the alternative site. Such comments should be flagged and deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The only acceptable circumstance I can see is if the question was closed as off-topic, and the proposal is a relevant potential site where they *could* post the question if the site existed.

However, if the question is a valid and on-topic question for the site, then all you're doing is advertising your Area 51 proposal which is not constructive to the question at all.

Another thing to think about: would linking to this Area 51 proposal *really* help anyone? Anyone looking for the question, even if it's only that single person who asked, wants the answer *now*. I doubt they'd be interested in waiting around for a site to be created (which may never happen) and then reposting the question to get an answer.